# Python 2.7 - Edit Specific Row,Column in CSV

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV with a bunch of data, and I need to change the data in a specific row and column.  I'm able to read through the file, find the row,col that I need to change, change the data, but I can't figure out how to commit that change to memory and re-write the CSV correctly.

The following code does not fail, however it is not correct.  Instead of committing the changes that I make to the column (col), it just duplicates the row that I want to change.  The data is unchanged, and now I just have duplicate rows where I wanted changes.

```
import csv
import re
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import shutil

csvName = raw_input("Enter the filename: ")
tempfile = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
newSize = 0
newArea = 0

with open(csvName, 'rb') as readCSV, tempfile:
    reader = csv.reader(readCSV)
    writer = csv.writer(tempfile)
    for row in reader:
        for col in row:
            if col.startswith('Connection:'):
                print col
            if col.startswith('Size:'):
                print "Current", col
                newSize = raw_input("Enter new size: ")
                newArea = int(newSize)*int(newSize)
                col = re.sub('[0-9]+', newSize, col)
                writer.writerow(row)
            if col.startswith('Area:'):
                col = re.sub('[0-9]+', str(newArea), col)
                writer.writerow(row)
        writer.writerow(row)

shutil.move(tempfile.name, csvName)
```

This is an example of one bit of data that needs to be changed:

Connection:  D14Conn
Type: B2B
Size: 140
Geometry: Square
Area: 19600

My code above will simply duplicate new rows into this data, and the changes I make to col are not committed - as below

Connection:  D14Conn
Type: B2B
Size: 140
Size: 140
Geometry: Square
Area: 19600
Area: 19600

Answer (score 1):

When you assign to `col` you are assigning to a copy of the col value in row. As you iterate through `row`, you need to either keep reference to the index of the value you want to change, and update `row` at that index so that when you call `writer.writerow(row)` you are actually writing with a changed object, or create a `new_row` with the desired columns.
As for your duplicates, remove `writer.writerow(row)` calls from your if blocks, they are redundant.

Comment: I figured that this is what I needed to do.  So, I just need to keep track of which row number I've iterated to, and then which column number I've iterated to, and then change the value at that row/col, right?

Comment: `reader` is an iterable object, so you will not necessarily benefit from tracking the row number, but you do not need to as each `row` will simply be an array of values. So if the 3rd column in the row you're looking at should be updated simply say `row[2]= ___` and then your `writer.writerow(row)` will reflect the update

Comment: So I understand your answer, but now I'm having trouble with execution.  It doesn't seem that csvReader keeps track of the csv in Row:Column format.  When I try the following code while keeping track of iterations, I just end up with a "list index out of range" error which I assume is because of my attempt to refer to column number:

Comment: row[rowNum][colNum] = re.sub('[0-9]+', newSize, col)

Comment: No problem dude! Brush up on iterator objects in Python. They aren't indexed, they simply implement __iter__() and next() functions, which is usable in a statement with `in` such as your `for row in reader`

Answer (score 0):

Your `row` isn't changed. You need to make a `new_row` with your new column values and do `writer.writerow(new_row)`